# Doing a SUMIF in Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, modelbuilder, field-calculator

There is a way to do a SUMIF, from EXCEL, in Model Builder? I tryed something like this in field calculator, but i can't iterate through an attribute from the attribute table.

```
def AreaTotal(A,B):
    for i in range(0,len(A)):
        aux=0
        for n in range(0,len(A)):
            if A[i]==A[n]:
                aux= aux+B[n]
            else:
                continue
        return(aux)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do exactly. What is A and B? Have you tried Summary Statistics tool? You might need to select by attributes first.

Comment: A and B are attributes at my atribut tabel. I'm trying to vectorize they, so I can compare if the key, at vector A, appears at vector B, then sum the values that match the key at another variable. I will read the Summary Statistics documentation. Thank you!